# How to save a cropped image on stage and load into another swf with air

Tags: actionscript-3, file, arrays, filestream

i have a problem. The main problem is in my apk , there are 3 swf file.
first swf file decides who can be the second swf between swfA and swfB.

for example swfA is chosen. swfA takes a screenshot of an cropped area and load main swf again. i need to load this screenshot into main swf right now. but it is not visible on the screen. it doesnt load. where is the point that i miss ?

save an image code is :  (class main for swf1)

```
    public function takeScreenshot():void 
    {
        import flash.display.Bitmap;
        import flash.display.BitmapData;
        import flash.utils.ByteArray;
        import flash.net.FileReference;
        import PNGEnc;

        var myCroppedImage:Bitmap = crop(232, 121, 188, 570, this);



        var d:BitmapData = new BitmapData(myCroppedImage.width, myCroppedImage.height);
        d.draw(myCroppedImage);

        var bild:ByteArray = PNGEnc.encode(d);

        var newImage:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("app:/yeniResim.png");
        var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        fileStream.open(newImage , FileMode.UPDATE);
        fileStream.writeBytes(bild);
        fileStream.close();
         //isimGoster.visible = false;

    }

    public function crop( _x:Number, _y:Number, _width:Number, _height:Number, displayObject:DisplayObject = null):Bitmap
    {
       var cropArea:Rectangle = new Rectangle( 0, 0, _width, _height );
       var croppedBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap( new BitmapData( _width, _height ), PixelSnapping.ALWAYS, true );
       croppedBitmap.bitmapData.draw( (displayObject!=null) ? displayObject : stage, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -_x, -_y) , null, null, cropArea, true );
       return croppedBitmap;
    }
```

load an image into another swf : (class main for swf 2)

```
       public function frame4():void {
        stop();

        resim = new Loader();
        var meRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest('app:/yeniResim.png');
        resim.load(meRequest);
        var mce:MovieClip = resim.content as MovieClip;
        mce.x = 480;
        mce.y = 320;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not waiting for the `Loader` to finish loading the file before you access its content. For example, it is likely that "content" in this line below does not contain the loaded image at the time you try and use it:

```
var mce:MovieClip = resim.content as MovieClip;
```

It's been a long time since I did anything in Flash, so this code may not be quite right. But I'm very certain you need to do something like this:

```
    var mce:MovieClip;
    resim = new Loader();
    resim.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imgLoaded);  
    var meRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest('app:/yeniResim.png');
    resim.load(meRequest);
    function imgLoaded(event:Event):void 
    { 
        mce = resim.content as MovieClip;
        mce.x = 480;
        mce.y = 320;  
    }
```

The other alternative is not waiting for the COMPLETE event and just adding the `Loader` to the stage. However, since you want to cast `Loader.content` into a `MovieClip` you need to wait for the content to be loaded. Check this [example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e13.html) for more details.

It's also good to attach an event listener to handle any failures. `Loader.contentLoaderInfo` is a `LoaderInfo` object, you can see the other [events that it dispatches](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#eventSummary) in case you need to trouble shoot further.

Comment: thanks for your advice! i solved this problem btw :)